# Check if PDF viewer applet is running

Tags: java, javascript, html, pdf, applet

I have third party applet to view PDF files on my page, and I need to ensure that user is allowed to run applet.  Is there any way from Javascript to check if applet is running?

Comment: To be certain, are you are talking about a _Java applet_?

Comment: Yes , I have downloaded some applet to view PDF files , and I want ensure that user allowed this applet to run

Comment: why use java applet for this ? Try http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/

Comment: @eicto  That script is brilliant in FF & Chrome on Windows, but IE 8.0.7601.. fails with `Message: Expected ':'` on 5 separate line numbers (the progress bar does not progress, the icons do not get loaded..).  But as someone who has deployed many applets, I also would be looking for a JS (or other non-applet) based solution to displaying PDF - purely for the reason of accessibility. +1 for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to Write another small applet , that in OnInit() function , throws callback to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if applet is alreay running use `isActive` function:

```
function appletPoll(onReadyCallback, id) {
    try {
        if (typeof document[appletId] != 'undefined' && 
            document[appletId].isActive())
             return onReadyCallback(document.applet);
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        appletPoll(onReadyCallback, id);
    }, 400);
}
```

Tested to work in Chrome, FF, IE > 7.